# How do you keep the scope when using SweetAlert2 with Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sweetalert, sweetalert2

When I attempt to add a [SweetAlert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io) to my delete button in angular, it prevents the scope from update the model.  Is it possible to use them both together?

[Shown here in this Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/7bJIC7ojq38Rja44Ibo0?p=preview)
(make sure you add an item first and then you can delete in the example)

Code with SweetAlert that doesn't work (nothing happens when I confirm):

```
function fieldToolsController($scope, ParticipantFactory) {
  var model = this;
  model.participant = ParticipantFactory;
  model.participant.hasRoles = model.participant.roles.length > 0;

  model.deleteSelectedRole = function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < model.participant.roles.length; i++) {
      if (model.participant.roles[i] === model.participant.selected) {

        swal({
          title: 'Are you sure?',
          text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
          type: 'warning',
          showCancelButton: true,
          confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
          cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
          confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
        }).then(function () {

          //=============================
          //LOSES SCOPE HERE OR SOMETHING
          //=============================
          model.participant.roles.splice(i, 1);
          model.participant.hasRoles = model.participant.roles.length > 0;
          if (model.participant.hasRoles) {
            model.participant.selected = model.participant.roles[0];
          }
          return;
          //=============================
          //=============================
          //=============================

        });

      }
    }
  };
}
```

Here's the same function that works fine with a normal javascript alert:

[And the plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/1MaKjUwzcgeqFRbXHJmI?p=preview)

```
function fieldToolsController($scope, ParticipantFactory) {
  var model = this;
  model.participant = ParticipantFactory;
  model.participant.hasRoles = model.participant.roles.length > 0;

  model.deleteSelectedRole = function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < model.participant.roles.length; i++) {
      if (model.participant.roles[i] === model.participant.selected) {

        var c = confirm("Are you sure?");
        if(c){
          model.participant.roles.splice(i, 1);
          model.participant.hasRoles = model.participant.roles.length > 0;
          if (model.participant.hasRoles) {
            model.participant.selected = model.participant.roles[0];
          }
          return;

        }

      }
    }
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the function is being executed later (it's a promise), you may need to provide the `model` variable as an injected parameter.

In your `.then` function, try injecting the `model` variable into it like this:

```
.then(function(model) {
    console.log(model)
});
```

Comment: Yeah - I definitely tried that.  I was hoping it would be that simple too. Gives this error: `app.js:26 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of undefined`